# Connection string of SQL Server 2008 R2 silent install

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, installation, connection-string

I have a Windows application that works with a local database (SQL Server 2008 R2). I'm trying to create an install for my application.

I want the installer check if SQL Server 2008 R2 is available in user system, installer doesn't install SQL Server and if there isn't any version of that the installer install a new version.

But my users can't install SQL Server, so I need to install it in **silent mode**

Now I create a setup project in VS2010 that install SQL Server in silent mode ...

**Two questions** :

1. does the installer check for another version of SQL Server ? (I mean check if is available ...)
2. what will be the connection string after installing SQL Server? (if it just install one time in each PC so I can have one unique connection string in all pc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can check it by specifying a launch condition in your setup project
   **Launch Condition:**
   To create and manage launch conditions, you use the Launch Conditions editor in Visual
   Studio. You can access this tool by selecting your project in Visual Studio and then clicking the
   View menu. You will see an Editor submenu that contains several setup editors, including those
   for Registry, File System, File Types, User Interface, Custom Actions, and Launch Conditions
2. You should set the connection string in your application as
      `string connectionstring ="datasource = .; Initial Catalog = |DataDirectory|\DBName.mdb;Integrated Security=SSPI` I think this connection string will work.
   and if you are installing an sql sever express edition then

   string connectionstring ="datasource =.\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog =  |DataDirectory|\DBName.mdb";Integrated Security=SSPI;

Comment: Thanks, was good help. the connection string works well . but i need do that launch condition... i find the window but dunno how work with that . Can you help me ?

Comment: Welcome. Is it your answer ? If yes then mark it as answer, other wise Vote up it.

Comment: Do you see a Launch Condition folder ?

Comment: right click on it. Add a new launch condition.There are two main branches of the Launch Conditions editor 1)Search Target Machine it allows you to define the criteria to search for prior
to installation.this node contains nodes for searching for major and minor versions
of IIS. You can add file, registry, and Windows Installer search conditions.Launch Conditions This branch allows you to create new launch conditions that
define conditions that must be met prior to installation. These conditions can be
based on search conditions or other criteria (such as the operating system version).

Comment: one more thing in your windows application solution, go to Properties, Select Publish tab, There is a PreRequiste button on this window, select it a new popup window will open, This window contains .net framework all versions, Sql server database, click the sql server 2008 check box. And then publish this app, it will automatically create an setup for the app including sql server setup.

Comment: Thanks M8 . Was Really Help Full Gr8.